# How to change contents of .properties in Gradle upon war creation

Tags: java, gradle, war

I'm experimenting with Gradle's war plugin. At this point project is still using Ant. Its a standard webapp layout:

```
| - project
| ---- src/main/java
| ---- src/main/resource
| ---- src/main/webapp
| ---- src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

In `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` there's a properties file containing key `jawr.debug.on`. For development purposes, it is usually set to `true`. During release phase this property is changed to `false` using Ant's propertyfile task.

I'm unable to find similar way of performing this in Gradle. I did find snippet below, but its not changing said file inside the resulting war:

```
ant.propertyfile(
    file: "jawr.properties") {
    entry( key: "jawr.debug.on", value: "false")
}
```

What would be the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to filter it during war creation

```
war {   
        rootSpec.eachFile {
            if (it.name == 'UserMessages.properties') {
                filter { line ->
                    line.replace('@build.label@', "${buildLabel}-${stage}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works. However this creates a problem where inexact string may result in replacement not being processed. For some reason when replacing `filter` to `ant.propertyfile(file: it)` an error is produced. Is there any way to utilize proper property replacement instead of blunt string replacement?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no native support for something like your usecase. The options for filtering files are rather limited. See also https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:filtering_files